# Prestashop: How do I change my page title as an administrator

Tags: admin, title, prestashop

How do I change my page title (file attached) as an administrator? From the back office.

[Click here to view my example of "Page title"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1O8s9.png)

Answer (score 6):

To change your shop’s name in PrestaShop, first open your site’s Admin Control Panel,

1. Go to Preferences -> Store Contacts(Contacts)
2. Replace ‘Shop Name’ text box with your desired shop name.
3. Scroll down and click Save.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to change the site name?
You can do this from:

> Backoffice > Preferences > Store Contacts > Contact details > Shop
>   name

If you need to update CMS page:

> Backoffice > Preferences > CMS > Click Edit on page you want to change
>   -> Meta title

Comment: Hi!
Thank you for your prompt reply! But I can't seem to find any "Store Contacts"

https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B4tR5UQyg7OxSVZkOUNhMG1lb2M&usp=sharing

Comment: What version of Prestashop are you using? 
And do you have full ADMIN access?